# ActiveAdmin and AdminUser action_item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I'm trying to add an action_item to a AdminUser, in the docs it seems that ruby will use the single form of AdminUser but for some reasons none of :

admin_user
adminUser
adminuser

works

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
action_item :only => :index do
    link_to "Change password", change_password_admin_admin_user(adminUser)                 
end
```

For now there is no real way to form a valid url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show some logs. Make sure you have change_password method and a valid route to it.
Working code to display button for edit admin_user:

```
action_item( only: :show ) { link_to("Edit", edit_admin_admin_user_path(admin_user)) }
```

Comment: the link_to and everything works if I chose a different url. for example I can pass manually a user. I just don't know how is named the  local variable created by activeadmin.

Comment: Local variable name is admin_user. This is a working example.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it, apparently i was missing _url